# Scroll and read slickgrid table into memory

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, slickgrid

I have a slickgrid table that I am trying to read into memory using watir-webdriver. Because the full data often cannot be seen without scrolling down, I want to make a function that can scroll through the table and also be able to tally a count of all the rows as well as access any row that might or might not be hidden within it. Here's what I have so far:

```
class SlickGridTable

def initialize(element)
                @element = element
end
        ...

        def scroll_down
                location_y = 23
                while true
                        location_y += 1
                        $browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0, #{location_y});", @element)
                end 
        end 
end
```

However I am regularly getting this error:

`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 2):

I am also working with slickgrid, and considered a similar approach. Instead, I extended the Watir::Div class with a scroll_until_present method. Now we can scroll until present and then work with the data in the grid. I have not had the need to collect all the data after implementing this. Does not solve your problem with tallying rows, but does help find the records you are expecting to see.

```
# Extends the Watir::Div class to support slick grids
module Watir
  class Div
    # scrolls until it finds the item you are looking for
    # can be used like wait_until_present 
    def scroll_until_present
        scroll_height = browser.execute_script('return document.getElementsByClassName("slick-viewport")[0].scrollHeight')
        (0..scroll_height).step(20).each { |item| 
            browser.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("slick-viewport")[0].scrollTop = ' + item.to_s) 
            if present?
                # scroll a little more once the record is found
                item += 30
                browser.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("slick-viewport")[0].scrollTop = ' + item.to_s) 
                break
            end 
        }
    end
  end
end
```